# Generate all gallery thumbnails 'at one time', not 'on demand'

Tags: external-sd, 6.0-marshmallow, gallery, images, thumbnails

**Context:**

Hello, I am an amateur photographer and I recently moved from an old iPad to a Galaxy Tab S 10.5 with custom rom, Android 6.

On the iPad the thumbnails were created while importing photos from iTunes, and even at the first time I opened the gallery everything was there.

Now I just copy a Photo folder into the root of my microSD card and I use QuickPic Gallery (but any other gallery is the same) to view the photos. I have 2-3k pictures and every time I open a gallery for the first time i see only black squares and they slowly appear, same story when I open a photo full-screen.

**Short story:**

Pictures that I copy into the microSD card have no thumbnails.

*I don't want to wait for the creation on-the-fly when I open a folder or manually open everything after copying so the next time will be cached!*

**How can I trigger the creation of all necessary thumbnails just after I copied my photos?**

Thanks

Comment: How are you copying the files onto the SD card? Through MTP (on a USB connection to your PC), or by taking the SD card out, or something else?

Comment: I take the SD card out, and copy a 'photos' folder into the root of the SD. Inside the photos folder there are other 2 leves, like: F:\photos\2015\France\0001.jpg